# Was the ship destroyed in the final episode of Stargate SG-1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Was the technology and everything the Asgard gave SG-1 destroyed in the end or did they save it in the new timeline?

Comment: This is answered by simply _watching the episode_, is it not?

Answer (score 23):

As we can see in the SG-1 episode "[Unending](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/10.20_%22Unending%22_Transcript)", indeed for a brief moment the ship, called the [Odyssey](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Odyssey), and everything on board except Teal'c, was destroyed:

> **EXT—SPACE**:
> The time dilation field is now off. The Ori beam goes through Odyssey, breaking it apart and causing large explosions.
>
> **INT—LARGE ROOM ON ODYSSEY**: Teal'c stands in the middle of the room as it explodes around him, one set of windows after another.
>
> **EXT—SPACE**: The ships is completely engulfed in explosions, breaking apart.

However, immediately after that, time is reset due to a reverse time-field to the moment just before they would have been hit:

> **EXT—SPACE**: Suddenly all motion stops, then time starts to move backward as the
> explosion undoes itself to the point where the Ori weapons struck the
> ship.
>
> **INT—LARGE ROOM ON ODYSSEY**: The explosion undoes itself around Teal'c, who still stands within the special field.
>
> **INT—ODYSSEY BRIDGE**: Time has reversed fifty years, back to the moments before the final shot from the Ori ship. Daniel is again at one of the control
> consoles.

So, in the end both the ship and her crew were saved and SG-1 goes to yet another mission:

> **INT—SGC GATE ROOM**: The wormholes comes to life.
>
> **LANDRY**: Good luck, SG-1.
>
> **MITCHELL**: Just another everyday mission to save the galaxy, sir.
>
> **ALL OF SG-1 IN UNISON**: Indeed.

The whole scene and the resetting of time can be seen here:

Comment: Both the Deadelus and Apollo both use plasma beam weapons a number of times (can't remember if the Hammond also uses plasma beam weapons), the Sun Zu is probably equipped with them

Comment: @SpacePhoenix The Hammond never seemed to (though the alternate Phoenix did, a lot) .. which seems strange since they were struggling against a bunch of Hataks.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it makes me wonder if the Hammond might have been in battle before the events of the start of Stargate Universe, during which perhaps the plasma beam weapons might have gotten damaged